# AWS API Gateway with Lambda function Cors enabled not working with Angular 5

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Tested CORS and its working fine. I'm getting response also from server.
API service call below

```
login (user: any) {
return this.http.post(this.url, user, httpOptions);
```

}

Angular component method that listens this api is below

```
this.auth.login(this.user).subscribe(
    data=>{
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error=>{
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  );
```

[image]

Please take a look at above image. CORS is working fine. But The subscribe is always falling into error. And the error message is below

```
{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. As long as we're using lambda proxy integration, we're responsible for handling response headers. Enabling CORS at api gateway will not add anything to your header. SO I've added "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to my header in lambda and now its working fine